# I am using large amount of data for comparison.. is there any idea for paging the data to datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable, paging

I am using large amount of data for comparison, while fetching records from DB getting hundreds of thousands of records and inserting to datatable, but its using more memory and performance is very very slow.. is there any idea for paging the data to datatable.

Comment: The best approach is to compare in the database instead of in memory. If that's nor possible for whatever reasons load only paged data into the `DataTable`. In SQL-Server you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

Comment: I required full data from DB, and Making conversion from isfoc to Unicode.. for this i required all data .. instead of fetching all data at a time we can fetch top 1000 once and next 1000 like that i have to do ..

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it. This is may be one of many solutions. If lets say, you have a table `MainTable`, create temp table `TempTable` as follows

```sql
Select Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS RowNum into TempTable from  MainTable
```

This will create a reference for the records at the moment of the job start. So, if any records will be deleted or added, they will not break your code.

Now, in c#, first, retrieve `max(RowNum)` and using this and `pageSize` you write logic, in which you select portions of your records in calculated loop where you retrieve data as following

```sql
Select mt.* from MainTable mt inner join TempTable tt on mt.id = tt.id and tt.rownum between <startRow> and <endRow>
```

Where `startRow` and `endRow` a calculated values. The return of such query may be not exactly a page size you setup, if some rows were deleted while your long-running job is running. And then clean up your temp table.